# Flask, how do i get Models results?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to get an output of roles into menu list and i am getting.

```
roles = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Role.query.filter_by(front=True), allow_blank=True)
```

and i am getting

```
project.models.Role object at 0x7f0205ec5cd0
```

what's the correct way to get the Role->name ?
here is my model:

```
class Role(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20), index=True)
    front  = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    #permissions = db.relationship('Permission', backref='permission')
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='roles')

    def __init__(self, name, front):
        self.name = name
        self.front = front
```

and here is my Form

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=50, message="You must enter a min and max character")])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password2', message='Your Passwords must be same')])
    password2 = PasswordField('Re-Enter Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password', message='Passwords must match.')]) 
    village = QuerySelectField(get_label='village', query_factory=villages_lists)
    roles = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: Role.query.filter_by(front=True), allow_blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selected model is available in the data attribute of the form's fields.

e.g. after receiving a post back you can do something like:

```
form = RegisterForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
   print form.roles.data.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your `Role` object a string representation that `wtforms` can use.

For example, in your current code you would get the following:

```
r = Role.query.first()
print(r) # project.models.Role object at 0x7f0205ec5cd0
```

If add the following to the Role class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

The object will now have that as it's representation, so if we run the same code again:

```
r = Role.query.first()
print(r) # Admin
```

`wtforms` uses that representation to set the displayed value for the elements in the field, so once you have that set (and returning a useful representation) you'll get it working the way you expect.